# creating a disolvable ik rig in blender for unity3D mecanim

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I am currently working on a game where I want to be able to add animations quickly and tweak them easily, yet have the rig itself play nicely with the unity3D engine. So basically all the features of a movie rig...without said movie rig showing up in the final product. The problem is that if I have too many control bones, they would appear in unity as useless empty game objects, and end up cluttering the workflow inside unity.

So my question is, is it possible to make a control rig in such a way that upon export to fbx, all important action animations are baked into the deform bones and the control rig essentially 'disolves' leaving behind only the deform rig in the game engine? If so, any pointers on how to go about it?

Comment: I need to point out this is not the same as getting a deformation rig to be compatible for both blender and mecanim. I already have that worked out.